# making archive with perl, when path is with spaces

Tags: perl

How can I use path with spaces in a perl script, running Archive commend?

Saying this is the command with the path I need:

```
C:\\"Program Files"\\7-Zip\\7z.exe a d:\\views\\"My views" d:\\"Public view"
```

Someone has an idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although it isn't a Perl question, you can use this syntax

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a target.zip "c:\path with spaces\example.pdf"
```

And if you need to call from a perl script

```
$cmd = q!"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a target.zip "c:\path with spaces\example.pdf"!;
system $cmd;
```

Comment: Do you know if I try use 'open(FILE, "path with spaces")' why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

If you use the [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) command with multiple arguments, each of them is passed unmodified to the invoked program:

```
system 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe', 'a',
       'd:\views\My views', 'd:\Public view';
```

Comment: You could probably switch to `c:/Program Files/...` to avoid yet another source of quoting confusion.

Comment: @mu: Yes, that would work too: Windows accepts both \ and / as path delimiters.